# Calculate adjusted / reciprocal values from a sequence of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

## tl;dr (summary)

I'm a beginner in mathematics. My question is: is there a formula to calculate the right column in the following table based on the values of the left column?

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline {\rm AwardedCount} & {\rm CalculatedScore} & {\rm ExpectedScore} \\
\hline 1303591 & 10 & 10 \\
\hline 108023 & 186 & 125 \\
\hline other data & … & … \\
\hline 12114 & 339 & 250 \\
\hline 20 & 790 & 500 \\
\hline 1 & 1000 & 1000 \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

Note that they are only examples of expected values, I just want to show the distribution I want at the end.

The `ExpectedScore` value should be: $ExpectedScore = [10, 1000]$

The middle column show the score I was able to calculate. The formula I currently use is (thanks to [MPW](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/630924/119611) and [Brian Rushton](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/634905/119611)):

$$
CalculatedScore = \Big(\big(1 - \log(AwardedCount; MaxAwardedCount)\big) \times 990 \Big) + 10
$$

The $log()$ function use two arguments, the first is the input value and the second is the base, hereby `MaxAwardedCount`.

This formula is what I was looking for, but I keep this question opened just in case someone have a simpler idea.

## Original question with details

(Adjust scores based on rarity)

I'm working on a [personal project](https://stackapps.com/questions/4467/truebadges-a-combination-of-stackexchange-badges-and-trueachievements) which involves calculating scores based on badges earned on StackExchange badges. I want to calculate a score from 1 to 1000 based on the rarity of a badge. A badge awarded to a few users (eg. only one user) should have a score of 1000. A badge awarded to a numerous users should have a lower score (always greater or equal to 1).

Let's take some examples:

- The most awarded badge is [Popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question), earned 1303591 times, let's call it `MaxAwardedCount`
- One of the least awarded badge is [castle-activerecord](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/281/castle-activerecord), earned only once
- Another badge [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) was awarded 108023 times, let's call it `AwardedCount`
- The [Favorite Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) badge was awarded 12114 times

## Current method

My formula is :

$$
Score = \frac{\frac{MaxAwardedCount}{AwardedCount}}{MaxAwardedCount} \times 1000 = \frac{1000}{AwardedCount}
$$

The value is then rounded to the superior integer value.

### Results

The Famous Question badge, most earned (108023 times): $\frac{1000}{108023} = 0.009257 \approx 1$

A rare badge, awarded only 20 times: $\frac{1000}{20} = 50$

A rare badge, awarded only twice: $\frac{1000}{2} = 500$

A rarest badge, awarded only once: $\frac{1000}{1} = 1000$

## Expectation

The problem is that it gives significant scores only to rare badges. Is it possible to find a formula which will give bigger scores even to more common badges?

Plus, a badge earned 10 times on sites A and B is more valuable on site A if A have more users than B (it is less frequent on A than on B). So the score has to been adjusted depending on the `MaxAwardedCount` value for each site.

To go further, would it be interesting to calculate the mean of the award count of each badge in order to give a score of about 500 to the badge which are never rare nor frequent? Since I got all the data from StackOverflow badges, I have calculated that the average of `AwardedCount` is 2451.6115. Is it possible to give an arbitrary score of 500 to this badge, then calculate the score of all the other badges?

I don't know much about mathematics so please use only simple words.

Comment: You use the normal-distribution tag --- do you know what the "normal distribution" is? You make no reference to it in the question, so far as I can see.

Comment: I know the tag is not appropriate to my question but it was the closest I found which corresponded to my goal: create a distribution of numbers calculated from the sequence of numbers. You can't edit my question and remove the if you think it's bad to use it.

Comment: Then it sounds like there's no probability involved in the question at all, just an attempt to engineer a formula to explain some outputs. I'll edit the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend imitating reddit and using a logarithmic scale. So take $-\log(awarded/maxawarded)$ and scale it to 1000. This makes the difference between very rare and average much smaller.

Edit: So the real formula would be $10-(990/14)\ln(awarded/1303591)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A `$` is missing after your formula. I don't want to edit your answer just for one character.

Comment: This answer fits my need. I modified the formula as $Score = ((1- \frac{log(AwardedCount)}{log(MaxAwardedCount)}) \times 990 + 10)$ and the result is the one I expected.

Comment: Can the formula in my comment above be simplified?

Comment: Please explain what is `14` in the formula you added in your answer.

Comment: @n.1 It is log(1303592). It works out the same as your formula by log rules, but yours is better. By the way, how can I find out my score?

Comment: Find *your* score? I'm not sure that I understood your question. Anyway, to calculate a score of one of your badges, take a badge on StackExchange, then multiply the number of times you earned by `Score` you helped me to calculate.

Comment: The formula above has been simplified to: $Score = ((1 − \log{AwardedCount; MaxAwardedCount}) \times 990 + 10)$ (the second argument of the $\log{}$ is the base of the log).

Answer (score 3):

Is this difficult? The frequency $f$ of a badge could be thought of as a number from $0$ (no user has earned it) to $1$ (every user has earned it). So pick your favorite decreasing bijection $r:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ (such as $r(x)= 1-x$) and you have a measure of rarity. Scale and translate if you really want the range to be $[1,1000]$ (so use $1 + 999r$). I'm thinking you would calculate the frequency $f$ in the obvious way as (# users with the badge)/(# users). Then $r(f)$ (or $1 + 999r(f)$ if desired) is what you want.

You could tweak the bijection I suggest by trying $r_{\alpha}(x) = 1 - x^\alpha$, et cetera. Pick the function you want to control the behavior as you desire.

Comment: Well it't not about frequency, it's about rarity, so more like: #users without / #users.

Comment: @Nameless: Rarity and frequency are complementary. That's what $r$ does. In my simple example, note that 1 - with/users = without/users.

Comment: @Nameless: Perhaps I wasn't clear on how $r$ was to be used. I have edited the answer to add that clarification. Apologies.

Comment: @MPW : I'm sorry but I don't understand most of your answer. *favorite decreasing bijection* please give an example. And can you please give an example with a formula? I've updated my question with a table of expected results.

Comment: I don't know the number of users.

Comment: @MPW: Anyway, after some days away from this problem, I understood more clearly your answer and used your formula, please see the updates at the beginning of the question.